# Problem with binding in the Razor Components

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

I have problem with binding on input as shown below. After typing the first character to the input is triggered method "Evaluate" correctly, but the value on field _answer is null. When I type the next character so the value of _answer is first typed character. Binding is just one character behind.

How can I fix it?

Thank you

```
    <input type="text" @bind="_answer" @oninput="Evaluate"/>
```

Comment: I feel like we need more code here to understand the issue. What is `Evaluate`?

Comment: Evaluate is the method where I validate field _answer, this is the reason why I need an actual value of the input. If you need all code I will share it, but I am not sure if it is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

`oninput` gets triggered before input is typed, use `onchange` instead.

Comment: But onchange is triggered when is focus on input lost. While oninput is triggered whenever a value is changed, this is mean every time if you write or delete something in your input. I need the second solution - oninput, but I also need actual value. :-( Thank you for your answer